# Cointegration in R - Standard error, test statistic and p-value of weights

Tags: r, time-series, econometrics, cointegration, causality

I'm using `urca` package in R version 3.2.1. I used `ca.jo` function on a set of I(1) regular time series variables - taking two at a time - to check for cointegration. The loading matrix, which I believe is the cointegrating equation's coefficient matrix, shows the estimated coefficients, but does not have the corresponding standard error, t-stat or p-value. How do I determine whether variable `x(t)` has a long run causal effect on variable `y(t)`?

Comment: I believe indeed urca does not provide standard errors for the cointegrating vectors.

Comment: @Matifou: Any alternative?

Comment: ok, see answer below

Answer (score 4):

As mentionned, I don't think urca/vars offers standard errors. You could either use another software like Gretl, or use a bootstrap procedure with package tsDyn:

```
library(tsDyn)
library(vars)
data(Canada)

## original sample
ve <- VECM(Canada, lag=1, estim="ML")
coefB(ve)

## confidence intervals using the empirical distribution 

coefB_boot <- function(x) as.vector(coefB(VECM(VECM.boot(x), lag=1, estim="ML")))
apply(replicate(200, coefB_boot(x=ve)),1,quantile, probs=c(0.025, 0.975))
```

The bootstrap procedure here just uses the quantiles of the bootstrap distribution, and does not use more fancy methods like bootstrapping the t-stat (precisely because it is unavailable) so does not give the asymptotic refinement of bootstrap. It shoul nevertheless give you an approximation for the confidence interval (which you can still compare with Gretl to be sure)!